# Normalization of function to get probability distribution function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

I have a distribution function of random value $F_N (x)=Φ(x)+\frac{3}{50\sqrt{2π}} e^{-x^2/2} (x^3-3x)  \frac {6N^3+21N^2+31N+31} {N(2N+5)^2 (N-1)}+O(\frac{1}{N^2} )$.
The function depends on $N>2$ and it was derived as asymptotic expansion in the Central Limit Theorem. Due to the asymptotic expansion there is an error like [$O(\frac{1}{N^2})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157316/pros-and-cons-of-probability-model-for-permutations)

I need to calculate pdf and I am not sure how to do it. What will happens with the error of the approximation in pdf?

Comment: Assuming you are allowing an $x$ dependence in your $O(\cdot)$ notation, then such a bound does not yield any rigorous bound on the derivative, since there are bounded functions with arbitrarily large derivatives, for example $\sin(tx)$ is always bounded but taking $t\to\infty$ leads to a function with arbitrarily large derivative. So the $O(\cdot)$ term can dominate all the other terms after taking the derivative.

Comment: @pre-kidney Well. I mean a such dependence that the function of random variable results in normal distribution for large $N$ ($N \to \infty$). In other words the larger $N$ the less error we have. What would be pdf in that case?

Comment: As stated, there is no bound on the pdf given only the assumptions you have written. It is like saying: "I have a function $f(x)$ such that $|f(x)|\leq 1$. What is a bound on $|f'(x)|$?" And the answer is there is no bound, since $\sin(nx)$ satisfies the hypothesis but has derivative $n\cos(nx)$ which is unbounded as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: To put it in more intuitive terms, derivatives depend on infinitesimal change in function. So any bound of the type $F_N(x)=g(x)+O(f(N))$ becomes useless when the change in the function is on a scale smaller than the $O(f(N))$.

Comment: I see. What would be additional assumptions to get pdf? I derived the function from the physical process: mixing of diffusing particles(see the link of the article) to take into account the finite number $N$ of such particles. Let's say error <1% would be fine for the case. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2563v1.pdf

Comment: You should ask this in a separate question...

Comment: Thank you. I asked about it in a separate question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300730/assumptions-to-get-probability-distribution-function-for-physical-process