# Assumptions to get probability distribution function for physical process

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Some time ago, I derived the function of random variable for the physical process: [mixing of diffusing particles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2563v1.pdf) (see the link for more details) to take into account the finite number N of such particles.
$F_N (x)=Φ(x)+\frac{3}{50\sqrt{2π}} e^{-x^2/2} (x^3-3x)  \frac {6N^3+21N^2+31N+31} {N(2N+5)^2 (N-1)}+O(\frac{1}{N^2} )$

The function was derived as asymptotic expansion in the Central Limit Theorem. Due to the asymptotic expansion, there is an error like [$O(\frac{1}{N^2})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157316/pros-and-cons-of-probability-model-for-permutations). 
I guess that for practical usage, the error $\epsilon \le 1$% of such approximation  should be fine.

My question: what assumptions are required to get probability distribution function and what would be the final pdf?

The difference with normal distribution depends on the second summand:
$\frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}+\frac{3}{50\sqrt{2π}}\frac {6N^3+21N^2+31N+31} {N(2N+5)^2 (N-1)}e^{-x^2/2} (-x^4+6x^2-3)$

I think that the assumptions have to be in line with the case  $N \to \infty$ when we have normal distribution.

PS. pre-kidney user [advised](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299793/normalization-of-function-to-get-probability-distribution-function) to post a separate question about this topic.

Comment: It tends to take hard-to-obtain conditions to rigorously ensure that differentiating an asymptotic expansion results in the asymptotic expansion of the derivative, but at the same time that's usually the best guess.

Comment: @Ian For the particular case it is possible to prove the convergence of the expansion in the CLT. So, I stopped at $O(\frac{1}{N^2} )$ to be fine with error of a few %. What about getting pdf?

Comment: To be a bit more direct: if you have an asymptotic expansion $\sum_n f_n(x) y^{-n}$  for $f(x,y)$ as $y \to \infty$ then usually the best guess for an asymptotic expansion for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as $y \to \infty$ is $\sum_n \frac{\partial f_n(x)}{\partial x} y^{-n}$. But there is not a nice general theorem providing convenient conditions ensuring that this works.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I'd like to get pdf for the finite $N$. The larger $N$ the less difference with the normal distribution. So I need to select proper $N$ to see the difference while researching.

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting to get here? I don't understand how you're expecting to use an asymptotic expansion for the CDF to get non-asymptotic information about the PDF.

Comment: $\frac {d} {dx} F_N(x)=f_N(x)$ Would it be fine to use the probability density for fixed N? - pls see my correction in the question.

Comment: I don't think you're following: the point is that at best you can hope to get an asymptotic expansion for $f_N$ from the asymptotic expansion for $F_N$. And a good guess for how to do that is to term-by-term differentiate the expansion of $F_N$, but there is no general theorem to ensure that this can be done without really restrictive hypotheses. Thus one usually has to come up with an argument to justify it on-the-fly.